# Visual Studio Tool box is Empty

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional. Suddenly the tool box controls are disappeared

i try right clicking in the toolbox and select 'show all' but still i dont see the asp.net controls, here is the screen shot of toolbox

[image]

Comment: You don't see the ASP.NET controls? Your screenshot shows a Windows Form, wouldn't that make sense?

Comment: yes the asp.net controls does not show in asp.net project and windows control does not show in widows project

Comment: Then you might want to edit your question to jive with the screenshot... Tim's answer is the obvious one.

Comment: Your install might be borked; try repairing or reinstalling, making sure to select the correct package for your development environment.

Comment: FWIW, I had the same problem in a simple MFC dialog-based project for C++. The right-click "Reset Toolbox" worked, but no idea why the Dialog Editor group was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try reseting VS settings](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/4a9a2ce6-e8ce-4874-9bdf-bc2365b88dbe):

```
Devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

or

```
Devenv.exe /ResetSettings
```

Comment: You might try right-clicking on the Toolbox and resetting *it* before you resort to resetting *all* VS settings.

Comment: Code Gray: i did try resetting by right click but still the same

Comment: the above solution does not work, so `i end-up restarting my machine` wallah it started working as expected...!!!

Answer (score 0):

ReOpen the Visual Studio

Goto SSIS tab --> Click on SSIS Toolbox

The above steps helped in adding SSIS tool box instead of adding View -->Toolbox